# Running migration results in class not found even though isnt used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to run a migration file, but when it runs I get an

```
undefined class/module BookingLib::/......./db/migrate/20141216090123_migrate_old_advanced_price_data.rb:18:in `block in up'
```

Migration file:

```
def up
    add_column :advanced_prices, :seller_id, :integer
    add_column :advanced_prices, :buyer_id, :integer
    add_column :advanced_prices, :seller_type, :string
    add_column :advanced_prices, :buyer_type, :string

    Shipment.all.each do |shipment|
      advanced_price             = shipment.advanced_price

      next unless advanced_price
      advanced_price.seller_id   = shipment.carrier_product.company_id
      advanced_price.seller_type = Company.to_s
      advanced_price.buyer_id    = shipment.customer.id
      advanced_price.buyer_type  = Customer.to_s

      shipment.advanced_prices << advanced_price
      shipment.save! <====================================== Failing line 
    end

    remove_column :advanced_prices, :customer_id, :integer
    remove_column :advanced_prices, :company_id, :integer

  end
```

Shipment:

```
  class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  .........
  serialize :package_dimensions, PackageDimensions
  serialize :shipment_errors, Array
  serialize :shipment_warnings, Array

  validates :shipping_date,      presence: true
  validates :number_of_packages, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
  validates :package_dimensions, presence: true
  validates :dutiable,           inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
  validates :carrier_product,    presence: true
...
```

Even though the model im saving records on have nothing to do with that class. Anyone have an idea why this is?

Comment: Which line is line 18? I would guess it loads a constant which in turn (perhaps indirectly) tries to load `BookingLib`.

Comment: added a line to show it

Comment: Have a close look at the validations of your `Shipment` class. Does `Shipment` have any references (also indirectly!) to `BookingLib`?

Comment: Nope, validations never refers to the class. Besides, I dont get why it would be undefined, as I have a file with the class defined in. Although not an activerecord class, but should this affect the loading of modules/classes?

Comment: Can you post the `Shipment` model as well? You're right it should work with autoloading, but it might be a serialisation issue. What kind or error did it raise?

Comment: well the error is just class/module undefined, I attached some of the shipment code, showing validations and serialization

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67382/discussion-between-fivedigit-and-tarlen).

Comment: On a side note, depending on how large the `Shipment` table is, I would recommend using `find_each` instead of `each`...`Shipment.all.find_each`. This will reduce the amount of memory used and will loop through the shipments in batches instead of all at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turns out to be a serialisation issue.

When `PackageDimensions` is being deserialised, it in turn loads error classes defined inside the class `BookingLib`. Under development, Rails lazy loads classes using autoloading, but since the error is not defined in its own file, the autoloading cannot resolve the error constant.

A solution is to include a require in either `Shipment` or `PackageDimensions`:

```
require 'booking_lib'
```

This will make sure that the `BookingLib` class, and therefore the errors declared inside of it are loaded before deserialisation ever happens.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to do 'Shipment.reset_column_information' before 'Shipment.all.each do |shipment|'. This ensures that all Shipment data is loaded from database and cached data is not used.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/reset_column_information

This may not solve your problem but I do not have enough points to comment on the question.